# Notice: Undefined index передача $_POST без новых переменных

Tags: php

Подобная тема поднималась не один раз всеми ламерами сети, но я так и не нашел решения для данной проблемы:

> Notice: Undefined index: name

Можно создать новую переменную типа $name и сделать:

```
$name = null;
if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
```

и передавать переменную $name в функцию, но если я не хочу создавать новую переменную и хочу сразу передавать в функцию данные с поста:

```
add_user($_POST['name'],$_POST['surname'],$_POST['login'],$_POST['password']);
```

как избежать тогда Notice если есть пустые поля???
Спасибо заранее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для PHP7 можете сделать так

```
add_user(
    $_POST['name'] ?? null,
    $_POST['surname'] ?? null,
    $_POST['login'] ?? null,
    $_POST['password'] ?? null
);
```

Или для любой версии в начале своего скрипта объявляете все ожидаемые элементы

```
$_POST += array(
    'name' => null,
    'surname' => null,
    'login' => null,
    'password' => null,
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, плюсанул бы, да нет еще такой репутации... :)

Answer (score 0):

Символ `@` экранирует ошибки:

```
add_user(@$_POST['name'],@$_POST['surname'],@$_POST['login'],@$_POST['password']);
```

Так же можно в начале прописать

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)
```

Это скроет все ошибки типа `notice` (уведомления)

Но такое игнорирование ошибок считается нежелательным. Вместо этого можно сделать так, чтобы клиентская часть передавала серверу `null`, но это тоже ненадёжно.

*Side note: никогда не доверяйте данным от пользователя и не передавайте их в функцию сразу. Нужно обрабатывать данные либо в функции `add_user()`, либо до неё. Почему - гуглите "sql-инъекции" и "xss"*

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответ на мой вопрос из вашего сообщения я не получил, но научился приему @$ :)))
Я бы плюсанул, но пока что репутация не позволяет)